# Facebook Analytics not working with ios device

Tags: ios, facebook, analytics, facebook-ios-sdk

> I had added app analytic for such events in my application which
>   perfectly works with iOS Simulator, but not with iOS device

```
When I run it on iOS Simulator, it gives me below log

Events: [
  {
    "event" : {
      "_eventName" : "XXX",
      "_logTime" : 1446626494,
      "User ID" : "159",

    },
    "isImplicit" : false
  }
]
Flush Result : Success


When I run it on iOS device, it gives me below log

Events: [
  {
    "event" : {
      "_eventName" : "XXX",
      "_logTime" : 1446626494,
      "User ID" : "159",
    },
    "isImplicit" : false
  }
]
Flush Result : No Connectivity
```

Please help me if anyone know issue.

Comment: I am facing the same problem both in Simulator as well as in Device anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure that you are logged in with Developer Facebook ID in that
>   iOS device from which you had generated Facebook App ID.

Comment: Ohh.. Yes, I had made this mistake.. Thanks a lot for your answer... You had saved my time